# Jquery on event is not working with selector where as its working with Jquery(document)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Jquery on event  is not working with selector where as its working with Jquery(document)?

I have moved all page script to js file, all working fine but Event Handler Attachment are not working with element selector.

**here the problem i am facing after moving to js file:**

```
      $(document).ready(function () {

      //this event is not working
      $('.add-new').on('click',function(){

               //code  

      });

      //this event is working fine.
      $(document).on('click','.add-new', function(){

             //code 

      });

     });
```

Because of some dependencies i am using jquery version 1.7.1 and 2.1.2

the sequence of these jquery and page js file as follow.

```
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

 //page js where from i have moved all page js to this file
<script src="/Scripts/ShowCollectionData.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

and using of  $(document).on('click','.add-new', function(){}) would not be the correct way.

am i doing wrong somewhere ?

Comment: Why are you using two different versions of jQuery?

Comment: Does `.add-new` exist at document ready?

Comment: Does the `.add-new` element exist on your page when the document ready handler is executed?

Comment: because of some dependencies i am using different vesions of jquery.

Comment: ans yes  of course this code is inside $(document).ready()

Comment: .add-new item is newly added element on the page.

Comment: is .add-new item added dynamically?

Comment: ".add-new item is newly added element on the page" ← What does this mean? When is it added?

Comment: .add-new element is dynamically added element using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).on('click','.add-new', function(){
     //code 
  });
  $('.add-new').on('click',function(){
     //code  
  });
```

Both of your declarations are valid.

The former works for dynamically added elements. You use document because you're delegating events on children of the document object, so events bubble up to the document level. It's also more convenient to select the closest parent you can (and the parent must exist on the page at load).

The latter still works, and is a preferred way to simply bind events to specific elements.

You can read more for on() [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).